# 'You don't exist, go away' - what does this heroku error mean?

Tags: git, heroku

So i'm pushing my code like usual and:

> git push heroku master
>   You don't exist, go away!
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Does anyone know what this is supposed to mean?

Comment: That's an ssh error message, it means that your user id could not be found in the password entry. Were you able to push with those credentials before? It could be a server misconfiguration on their part.

Comment: Yes, just minutes prior to that error I was able to push. Could resetting my heroku credentials fix this? How would I do this?

Comment: I would email Heroku for help. It sounds like a problem with the server.

Comment: What a well-written and totally non-insulting error message :-D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried pushing to heroku again today and it auto magically worked. No changes on my part.

Thanks for all the ideas from everyone else though, I was about to do all that stuff but I wanted to give it one shot before diving in, and it just worked.

I guess we'll never know what it really was...

Comment: The answer given by Magnus solved this issue for me.  You might consider marking his answer as the solution.

Answer (score 16):

If you're pushing from OS X then it's probably this funky state OS X gets into where your user doesn't know its own identity -- you can confirm by typing the "id" command where you'll see your username is missing, or trying to sudo which won't work.

For some reason this seems to fix it:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me -- thanks! The `id` command did not display my username before I flushed, but it did afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this:

```
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Tells us about connection problem.
But this:

```
You don't exist, go away!
```

Usually means that SSH **client** can't resolve your user name(LDAP error?)
So, I thinks, it's a problem on your side, but to resolve it, there should be more information.

Answer (score 3):

You might have nscd running. The thing caches passwd entries so that programs don't waste their time parsing /etc/passwd, calling NIS, LDAP, or whatever.

If the thing's database gets corrupted (unlikely, these days), or if it caches a negative answer (much more likely), it can drop arbitrary users from its cache.
"sudo nscd -i passwd" should work.

If that doesn't fix it, kill nscd so that requests are no longer cached. Fix the problem. Then remove `/var/cache/nscd/passwd` and restart nscd.

This can happen if LDAP/NIS/whatever doesn't answer in time, and the non-answer is misinterpreted as "nonexistent entry" instead of "service problem".

Answer (score 0):

Often this is caused by a process that was running before authentication credentials for the user were change. (ie. password change)

sshd can cache the credentials for the user, which will mean the pre-change ones will still be in effect. Restarting services which use ssh will fix the problem.